# How can I add a pet to PCGen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen

In my game I have gained a pet. The kind is not important. I have gotten a Circlet of speaking that I want to give the animal. Is there a way on PCGen to a) make a sheet for the pet without it trying to give it levels, and b) equip the item to it and not to me?

I actually have two, one was found as an egg. it is purely for flavour. they would die if they actually fought.

Comment: Is this an animal companion, or a pet as in "I picked up a stray cat and take care of it" pet?

Comment: the cat one... I actually have two, one was found as an egg. it is purely for flavour. they would die if they actually fought

Comment: @Maldrek you should put that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the Companion's Tag and add a Follower, but it's limited to the races in the program. So unless your cat is a young leopard or something similar you will have to build it by hand (or by using the "Race Builder" race if you are using Pathfinder)